# Different mechanism to decide on which file to take (two files with same name) in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, packaging

I'm currently facing a rather strange problem, since it happens with the same Eclipse project, but only on some computers (installations of eclipse IDE).
The problem occurs so far on computers which have installed eclipse version 2019-12 (4.14.0) and eclipse fortune (very old, sadly I do not know the exact version).
It does not occur on my laptop (2020-03 (4.15.0)) and on another laptop with version 2019-06 (4.12.0).
This information about the versions is just because I want to give you as much information as possible, right now I think it's more likely that the problem does not depend on the eclipse version, but on some private eclipse settings or something like that.

I have two Projects, Project A and Project B. Project B requires Project A on its build path to compile and to run on a server.
In both projects, there is a folder webapp with static content like images and so on.
I've added the webapp folder of Project A as a Linked Resource (Properties > Resource > Linked Resources) to Project B so that I can access static content of Project A in Project B (there are some more projects in development and using code of Project A, so it is very useful when I only have to put an image in the webapp folder in project A and every other project can directly access it).

Now I have two images with the same name, let's say for instance "image.png" in the webapp folder of project A and in the webapp folder of project B. I want that in such a case, when there is a file in both webapp folders witht the same name, that the one from the folder in project B is picked and uploaded to the server. I think it's possible and the file to pick is determined by the file *org.eclipse.wst.common.component* in the .settings folder of eclipse.

In this file, depending on the order in which you added both of the webapp folders to the Deployment Assembly for the project (Properties > Deployment Assembly), both folders are written down. The usual behaviour should be that the files from the first webapp folder noted in that settings-file are picked first in case of a name conflict. On my laptop, this works just fine, but on other laptops it's not working and always the file from project A is taken.

Now I think maybe there are even more, some "hidden" eclipse settings or sth like this to determine how these files are picked and how name conflicts are resolved. Because the code and the eclipse settings files are identical and on one computer it works and on other ones not (I tried on 5 laptops, on 3 it's working and on 2 it won't).

I'm really stuck here, so if anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any idea, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Janosch

Answer (score 0):

In your long text you basically say that you have a classpath with several directories. Within the classpath there are two file with identical subpath, such as

```
classpath
   +- dir A
   |   +- subdir
   |       +- file
   +- dir B
       +- subdir
           +- file
```

So when you try to access the resource `subdir/file` you always get the one from `dir A` and you would prefer to get the other.

It is a definition that the first match on the classpath is returned. If you want the other, change the sequence on your classpath. If you want to influence the classpath at JVM runtime or support other locations than class files (.class) and zipped class files (.jar) you can still ensure these classes get loaded via the correct [Classloader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). This is what application servers use to separate the different applications from each other.

Comment: The classpath and directory structure is correct. But strangely not every time or more concrete on every laptop the first file or like you said the first match on the classpath is returned. On my laptop it works just as you described but on the laptop of two of my colleagues, the order of the dirs and files make no difference. Always the file from dir B is shown and never the other one. 
Maybe you can change this behaviour somewhere in eclipse settings and this is the reason for the different behaviour. Are there such settings or is it totally unchangeable and first match is always returned ?

Comment: If you have a clear view of what needs to get loaded make use of your own classloader. With that you can tightly control what gets loaded when.